# Calling @GetMapping "/" on external tomcat throws error - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8, request-mapping, contextpath, get-mapping

I developed a spring boot application and deployed on external tomcat. What I am facing is when I call application through context path tomcat throws an exception.

Controller

```
@GetMapping(value="/",  produces = "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    public String loadIndexPage() { 
        return "index";
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <finalName>apluscontent</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I expect application runs on http://localhost:8080/apluscontent/ but it throws below exception

> Forwarding to error page from request [/index.html] due to exception [Failed to find lookupPath '/index.html' within requestUri '/apluscontent/'. Does the path have invalid encoded characters for characterEncoding 'UTF-8'?]
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find lookupPath '/index.html' within requestUri '/apluscontent/'. Does the path have invalid encoded characters for characterEncoding 'UTF-8'?

Comment: is there an explanation ?

Comment: The issue was solved. I put the index.html under templates rather than in webapps